# Синхронизация (изменение значений) Edit используя Dll

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-xe, delphi-xe7

Как передать (изменить) данные в Edit (любой текст или сумму или отнять) используя .dll. **Получаю ошибку при компиляции set.dll** в виде:
[dcc32 Error] Project1.dpr(8): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'Edit1'

**Проект set.dll:**

```
library Project1;

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Classes, Vcl.Dialogs;

  procedure EditPROC; export;
begin
 Edit1.Text:='OK';
end;

exports EditPROC;

{$R *.res}

begin
end.
```

**А вот код самой программы VCL:**

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
// подключаем set.dll
  procedure EditPROC; external 'set.dll';

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
// Запускаем set.dll и передаем данные из EditPROC в программу
EditPROC;
end;

end.
```

Где допускаю ошибку ?

Comment: А где вы создаёте `Edit1`?

Comment: @zed, В самой программе VCL. Мне просто нужно что бы при запуске программы, текст из DLL изменял текст в Edit (что в VCL) на "OK". То есть Edit1.Text = 'OK';

Comment: В коде, что вы привели в вопросе, у программы нету Edit1. И так, как вы пытаетесь сделать в dll, на самом деле делать нельзя. Из dll надо возвращать указатель на строку (PAnsiChar/PWideChar), а уже в программе присваивать это значение текстовому полю эдита.

Comment: @zed, Я кажись понял как сделать. Сейчас переделаю и опубликую код.  Вы меня на Мысль натолкнули!.

Answer (score 0):

В общем вделал так:

```
Это код в DLL:
library Project1;

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Classes;

{$R *.res}

Function PlusMin (a,b, Index: Integer): Integer;
begin
  if index =0 then
  result:= a + b;

  if index =1 then
  result:= a - b;
end;
  exports PlusMin;
end.
```

А это код самой программы VCL:

```
 unit Unit1;
    
    interface
    
    uses
      Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
      Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;
    
    type
      TForm1 = class(TForm)
        Button1: TButton;
        Edit1: TEdit;
        Edit2: TEdit;
        ComboBox1: TComboBox;
        Edit3: TEdit;
        procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
      private
        { Private declarations }
      public
        { Public declarations }
      end;
    
    var
      Form1: TForm1;
    
    implementation
    
    {$R *.dfm}
    
    function PlusMin (a,b, integer: Integer): Integer;
   // Подключаем Dll 
    External 'dll.dll';
    
    procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    begin
// Вывод суммы или минуса (Edit1.Text -+ Edit2.Text) = в Edit3 через функцию (PlusMin) из DLL
    Edit3.Text:= inttostr(PlusMin (strtoint(Edit1.Text), strtoint(Edit2.Text), Combobox1.ItemIndex));
    
    end;
    
    end.
```

Вот таким способом нашел решение. Может кому и пригодится вариант. Для начинающих, как я.

Comment: @zed, Вот так решил задачу. А дальше уже можно манипулировать как угодно.